# VB.NET Launching Batch File not working after install

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, batch-file, permissions

Okay, this is one that has me stumped beyond belief. I have a program that is to be installed on different machines that is supposed to execute a batch file after it has completed a specific task. The batch file is configured via our webservice by the user, and the application pulls this path string down and then executes the file at that path. Should be pretty simple/straightforward, right?

The code:

```
Private Function ExecuteBatchFile(batchFilePath As String) As String
    Try
        Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(batchFilePath)
        psi.RedirectStandardError = True
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psi.CreateNoWindow = False
        psi.UseShellExecute = False
        Dim process As Process = process.Start(psi)
        process.WaitForExit()
        ExecuteBatchFile = process.ExitCode
    Catch ex As Exception
        StrAppStatus = "Error within execution of batch file: " & ex.Message
        LogMe(StrAppStatus)
        Return "Fail"
    End Try
End Function
```

Now, for the tricky part. This code works perfectly when running in the dev environment. I have yet to have an issue. HOWEVER, when the application is installed on any computer (including the same one the IDE is installed on), when it gets to the step in it's overall process that calls this function, it does not actually launch the batch file. Keep in mind, it never throws an exception, on either side. It also does not return an exitcode to that string, as i have other logging to track that as well.

There are only two possibilities I can think of in this case. Either A:) there is a permissions issue where the application is not allowed to launch batch files on the computer it is installed on, or B:) this sub is called by a thread that was spun off from the main thread (i.e. using the `MyThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf TheMainLoop) MyThread.Start()` command).

Still the fact that it works 100% of the time during the compile and run phase in the IDE but not after an install is blowing my mind.

**EDIT 1:**
Just did a test where I placed a button on the main form itself, and the click event does the same thing as the earlier function, and it works, even after an install. This leads me to believe that it will only work if it is launched using the main thread... What do you all think?

**EDIT 2:**
The batch file is a very simple test batch that opens a text file, and I know that the batch file and path are both fine, because when compiled it works fine. Also, edit 1 was stating that I created a simple button that executes the same code from above, and it works fine after an install. Since that was done on the main thread, and the code from earlier was done in a separate thread spun off from the original, I was wondering if that was the cause of the issue. 
The other crazy thing is that my logging catches if the file launches or not, and  it almost acts as if it is launching when I have that original issue. Bah, this whole thing is just nuts.

**EDIT 3:**
Added the answer.

Comment: Have you tried setting UseShellExecute to true?

Comment: Hmm. No I have not. I am not quite sure I understand how this whole command works. what is the difference between true and false for that propert?

Comment: From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page:  `Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use the operating system shell to start the process.  When you use the operating system shell to start processes, you can start any document (which is any registered file type associated with an executable that has a default open action) and perform operations on the file, such as printing, by using the Process object. When UseShellExecute is false, you can start only executables by using the Process object.`

Comment: The caveat to that is you can't redirect standard error or standard output.  However you might be able to do something with the `cmd` console and run the batch file as a parameter.

Comment: I am not sure if the previous suggestion did the trick (and, to be honest, I am pretty confused with EDIT 1), but I had problems in the past while caling batch files and, usually, the problem is not in the way you use to call it, but in the file paths (the ones of the called batch file and the ones written inside this file). If you have still a problem, could you please, post both the exact path you are using to call the batch file and the contents of this file?

Comment: I understand what the msdn site says, but I am not sure how that affects me here. Shouldn't it be launching because I am directly using the Process object. Now, I don't need the standard redirect error or redirect output, but I just wanted to make sure that setting this to true will be beneficial. I will run a test case. Only problem with that is that test cases on this end take a few hours to complete.

Comment: @BobbyNicholls I tried copy paste your code and ask it to run a batch file (d:\test\test1.bat" with it's contents "notepad d:\test\a.txt", it works fine. Anything else you can share with us? how about create a simple project code, zip, upload it somewhere (dropbox,rapidshare) and share usthe link so we can investigate further.

Comment: @Dennis, Right, that is what was so confusing, it would work when run from Visual Studio, but if I packaged it up into an install and installed it on any computer, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tinstaafl, the answer was to change UseShellExecute to True. I had to remove the RedirectStandardError and RedirectStandardOutput lines, but I wasn't using them anyways. On that note, thank you everyone for your investigations, and if anyone has an idea as to why this happened, I am all ears.